# How to pass the integer value into an SQL Query in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel, userform

I have written two queries inside the a method, where the output of the one query is fed as an input to another query. I tried passing the result(int) into the WHERE clause of the second query, but i'm getting the syntax error.

Below is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()



On Error GoTo UserForm_Initialize_Err
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim result As Integer

cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
         "Data Source=C:\Users\inkapb\Desktop\EPC Database\EPC TOOL.mdb"
rst.Open "SELECT [Project_Id] FROM [Project Details] WHERE [Project Name] = '" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & " ' ;", _
         cnn, adOpenStatic
'rst.MoveFirst

result = rst.Fields(0)
rst.Close

'Here in the below query i want to pass the result of the first query into WHERE clause


rst.Open "SELECT [Product Name] FROM [Project Details] WHERE [Project_Id] = ;" & result, _ 
         cnn, adOpenStatic
rst.MoveFirst

With Me.ComboBox2
    .Clear
    Do
        .AddItem rst![Product Name]
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop Until rst.EOF
End With
UserForm_Initialize_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
rst.Close
cnn.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
UserForm_Initialize_Err:
MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
Resume UserForm_Initialize_Exit


End Sub
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Remove semicolon in `..WHERE [Project_Id] = ;` to  `..WHERE [Project_Id] = `

Comment: No, still the error exits.
It Says " No Value given for one or more required parameters"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first query may not be finding the value to feed into the second query because of the extra space.

Change:

```
 '" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & " ' ;",
```

To:

```
'" & Me.ComboBox1.Value & "' ;",
```

Also, cast your integer to a string. Use VR46's query, although add:

```
 result.ToString()
```

The solution was to create a new connection and record set for the second query.

Comment: I kept an debug pointer and checked while execution, the result variable contains the value "1"

Comment: Dim result As Integer 
         
Dim value As string

result = rst.Fields(0)

value = value & CStr(result)

And in the query i changed the result into value

rst.Open "SELECT [Product Name] FROM [Project Details] WHERE Project_Id =  " & value, cnn, adOpenStatic

But still the same error!

Comment: Try using a new connection and a new record set for the second query.

Comment: Good to hear, I've updated the solution, please mark as answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You semicolon is misplaced as of now query is like

```
SELECT [Product Name] 
FROM [Project Details] 
WHERE [Project_Id] =;8
```

which should be

```
WHERE [Project_Id] =8;
```

Also there was a underscore here `;" & result, _` remove that as well.  Try something like this

```
rst.Open "SELECT [Product Name] 
          FROM [Project Details] 
          WHERE [Project_Id] = " & result & " ;", cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

or simply

```
rst.Open "SELECT [Product Name] 
          FROM [Project Details] 
          WHERE [Project_Id] = " & result , cnn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: may need an extra ampersand after result:  & result &

Comment: @VR46 I replicated the same code which you have commented but still the same error popping up! I don't know where i'm heading wrong

Comment: @KarthikPB - did u remove the `_` after `& result `

Comment: Yes, i removed it and put everything in one line

Comment: @KarthikPB - check now

Comment: After type casting from int to string the same error is popping out, i hard coded the value as "2" instead of passing the variable, surprisingly even that is throwing the error as "No value given for one or moew required parameters"



here is the hard coded query


 rst.Open "SELECT [Product Name] FROM [Project Details] WHERE Project_Id = 2 ", cnn, adOpenStatic

Comment: @KarthikPB - I have added another parameter check the code

Comment: No:( still the same error after adding the parameter!

Comment: That's all i can come up without knowing anything about VBA :D between am a T-Sql guy. Good luck

Comment: @VR46 I used other recordset as mentioned by Shep, and is working fine. Between thanks a lot for your efforts, Good Day mate!

Comment: @KarthikPB - Glad you got it